# How to get middle period of 2 date periods in ruby?

Tags: ruby

c should be inner period of 2 periods. How to get it in most elegant way?

```
a1=Date.current
a2=Date.current + 2.months

b1=Date.current + 1.month
b2=Date.current + 3.months

c=???

c.should_be [Date.current + 1.month, Date.current + 2.months]
```

Comment: @Sergio you don't want to see current implementation. your eyes will bleed.

Comment: I mainly want to know how hard you've tried :)

Comment: "what have you tried" isn't appropriate for general questions like this imho

Comment: @SergioTulentsev didn't try too hard. just got it working. but I'm not looking for any implementation, looking for elegant one. usually knowing how to do things best takes years of experience and i lack them atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hurried implementation:

```
xs = (a1..a2).to_a & (b1..b2).to_a
(xs.first..xs.last)
# => Sun, 24 Jun 2012..Tue, 24 Jul 2012
```

There is nothing special about a range of dates. So search "range intersection" to do it more efficiently (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414547/ruby-intersection-between-two-ranges)). Now you can write:

```
(a1..a2) & (b1..b2)
```

Comment: yap... intersection is the word i couldn't remember :)

Comment: Be careful that neither of your dates are really Time objects, or your range will have one element for every second between the two ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
d= [a1, a2, b1, b2]
[*1..d.length/ 2].map do |dt| 
    d.shift(2) 
end.map do |dx| 
    Date.current+ (dx[1]- dx[0]) 
end
```

[Sun, 24 Jun 2012, Tue, 24 Jul 2012]