# Merging Overlapping Intervals

Tags: python

Currently, I have intervals of:

```
temp_tuple = [[-25, -14], [-21, -16], [-20, -15], [-10, -7], [-8, -5], [-6, -3], [2, 4], [2, 3], [3, 6], [12, 15], [13, 18], [14, 17], [22, 27], [25, 30], [26, 29]]
```

in an ascending order by the lower bound. My task is to merge overlapping intervals so that the outcome comes out to be:

```
[-25, -14]
[-10, -3]
[2, 6]
[12, 18]
[22, 30]
```

My first attempt involved deleting intervals that are completely within previous intervals, like [-21, -16] which falls within [-25, -14]. But deleting objects within a list kept interfering with the loop condition. My second attempt at deleting unnecessary intervals was:

```
i = 0
j = 1
while i < len(temp_tuples):
    while j < len(temp_tuples):
        if temp_tuples[i][1] > temp_tuples[j][1]:
            del temp_tuples[j]
        j += 1
    i += 1
```

but this doesn't delete all the unnecessary intervals for some reason.
What should I do?

Comment: Instead of trying to delete from the list, build a new list with only the necessary elements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merging Overlapping Intervals in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49071081/merging-overlapping-intervals-in-python)

Comment: @Guybrush the other direction of closure should be applied (already voted)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It makes it a bit easier to process (as in think about) if you instead setup a new list. You additionally also get to keep your original data.

```
temp_tuple.sort(key=lambda interval: interval[0])
merged = [temp_tuple[0]]
for current in temp_tuple:
    previous = merged[-1]
    if current[0] <= previous[1]:
        previous[1] = max(previous[1], current[1])
    else:
        merged.append(current)
```

If you now `print(merged)` it would output:

```
[[-25, -14], [-10, -3], [2, 6], [12, 18], [22, 30]]
```

Comment: I know this is a dumb question, how come the "current" intervals change their upper bound if they were taken from the list temp_tuple?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. But the order doesn't *matter* because of the `temp_tuple.sort(...)`. Thus why we only have to check the last interval in `merged`.

Answer (score 10):

This is a numpy solution I came up with:

```
import numpy as np

def merge_intervals(intervals):
    starts = intervals[:,0]
    ends = np.maximum.accumulate(intervals[:,1])
    valid = np.zeros(len(intervals) + 1, dtype=np.bool)
    valid[0] = True
    valid[-1] = True
    valid[1:-1] = starts[1:] >= ends[:-1]
    return np.vstack((starts[:][valid[:-1]], ends[:][valid[1:]])).T

#example
a=[]
a.append([1,3])
a.append([4,10])
a.append([5,12])
a.append([6,8])
a.append([20,33])
a.append([30,35])

b = np.array(a)

print("intervals")
print(b)
print()
print("merged intervals")
print(merge_intervals(b))
```

Output:

```
intervals
[[ 1  3]
 [ 4 10]
 [ 5 12]
 [ 6  8]
 [20 33]
 [30 35]]

merged intervals
[[ 1  3]
 [ 4 12]
 [20 35]]
```

Please note that the input array must be sorted by start positions.

Answer (score 0):

The salient feature of the solution below is to run a list called `final` parallel to the input list. Before entering the `for` loop, the `final` list inserts the first array item in it. Then starts the comparison. That's it!

```
def merger(a):

    final=[]

    final.append(a[0])

    for i in range(1,len(a)):

        if a[i][0]<=final[-1][1]:

           if a[i][1]>final[-1][1]:

               low_limit=final[-1][0]
               hi_limit=a[i][1]
               final.pop()
               final.append([low_limit,hi_limit])

           if a[i][1]<=final[-1][1]:

                low_limit=final[-1][0]
                hi_limit=final[-1][1]
                final.pop()
                final.append([low_limit,hi_limit])

          if final[-1][0]<a[i][1]<final[-1][1]:

           low_limit=a[i][0]
           hi_limit=final[-1][1]
           final.pop()
           final.append([low_limit,hi_limit])



        else:
            final.append(a[i])

    return final

if __name__=="__main__":

    array=[[-25, -14], [-21, -16], [-20, -15], [-10, -7], [-8, -5], [-6, -3], [2, 4], [2, 3], [3, 6], [12, 15], [13, 18], [14, 17], [22, 27], [25, 30], [26, 29]]
    print(merger(array))
```

Output:

```
[[-25, -14], [-10, -3], [2, 6], [12, 18], [22, 30]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Given an array of intervals in sorted order and a new interval, return a sorted array after merging the interval

def mergeinter(intervals,newinter):
    n = len(intervals)
    start = newinter[0]# we mark the start and end of the new interval to be merged
    end = newinter[1]
    right,left = 0,0
    while right < n:# we track where this new interval belongs, i.e. how many interval are to the left of it and how many are to the right
        if start <= intervals[right][1]:# we find the first interval before which it fits
            if end < intervals[right][0]:# this checks if the interval is disjoint and lies between two given intervals
                break# in this case we have nothing to do and go to line 29 directly
            start = min(start,intervals[right][0])# if it intersects with the given intervals then we just update and merge the ends
            end = max(end,intervals[right][1])
        else:# counting how many to the left continuing from line 20
            left += 1 
        right += 1# moving right to find the fit continuation of line 20 and even if we merge in line 25, we go to the next interval before
    return intervals[:left] + [(start,end)] + intervals[right:] # we return starting from the next interval

#Given a collection of intervals, merge all overlapping intervals and return sorted list of disjoint intervals.

def merge(I):
    I.sort(key:lambda i:i[0])# sorting according to the start of all intervals
    res = []# we start from the last of the given arr of lists and check the ends of the intervals and merge from the end
    for i in I:
        if not res or res[-1][0] < i[1]:# if res is empty then we put an elem in it from I
            res.append(i)# if there is no overlap, just add it
        else:
            res[-1][1] = max(i[1], res[-1][1])# here we merge from the end so that res remains sorted
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some improvements based on [vallentin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43600953/105315), mainly using `copy.deepcopy` to prevent any changes to the input.

Note that using `sorted()` or `.copy()` is insufficient, as sub-elements get changed when any merge happens.

I also added a `.sort()` call on each interval to handle unsorted input, as well as a more explicit initial sort call for clarity.

**Code:**

```
import copy

def mergeIntervals(input_array, preserve_input=True):
    '''
    Python3 program for merging overlapping intervals.
    If preserve_input is False, the input_array can be modified! Not just sorted, but even sub-elements can change!

    See:
        https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-the-merge-overlapping-intervals-problem
        https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merging-intervals/
        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43600878/merging-overlapping-intervals
    '''
    if preserve_input:
        intervals = copy.deepcopy(input_array)
    else:
        intervals = input_array

    # Sort the given list of time intervals in ascending order of starting time.
    intervals.sort(key=lambda interval: interval[0])

    intervals[0].sort() # deal with unsorted input

    # Create a stack with the first interval
    merged = [intervals[0]]

    for current in intervals[1:]:
        current.sort() # deal with unsorted input
        previous = merged[-1]
        # Check for overlapping interval
        if current[0] <= previous[-1]: # If it’s overlapping, then merge them into one interval;
            previous[-1] = max(previous[-1], current[-1])
        else: # otherwise, push it in the stack.
            merged.append(current)

    return merged

##### Testing code:
A_list = []

# Example from original question:
input_array = [[-25, -14], [-21, -16], [-20, -15], [-10, -7], [-8, -5], [-6, -3], [2, 4], [2, 3], [3, 6], [12, 15], [13, 18], [14, 17], [22, 27], [25, 30], [26, 29]]
A_list.append(input_array)

# Example with unsorted elements and sub-elements:
input_array = [[4, 2], [3, 1]]
A_list.append(input_array)

for preserve_input in [False, True]:
    print(f'==> preserve_input = {preserve_input}')
    for idx, a in enumerate(A_list):
        print('------> idx = ', idx)
        input_array = copy.deepcopy(a)
        print('input before:', input_array)
        output_array = mergeIntervals(input_array, preserve_input=preserve_input)
        print('input after:', input_array)
        print('output', output_array)

        if input_array != a:
            print('Input modified!')
            if preserve_input:
                raise
        else:
            print('No change in input.')
```

**Output:**

Note in particular the change of `[22, 27]` to `[22, 30]` in the first example, near the end.

```
==> preserve_input = False
------> idx =  0
input before: [[-25, -14], [-21, -16], [-20, -15], [-10, -7], [-8, -5], [-6, -3], [2, 4], [2, 3], [3, 6], [12, 15], [13, 18], [14, 17], [22, 27], [25, 30], [26, 29]]
input after: [[-25, -14], [-21, -16], [-20, -15], [-10, -3], [-8, -5], [-6, -3], [2, 6], [2, 3], [3, 6], [12, 18], [13, 18], [14, 17], [22, 30], [25, 30], [26, 29]]
output [[-25, -14], [-10, -3], [2, 6], [12, 18], [22, 30]]
Input modified!
------> idx =  1
input before: [[4, 2], [3, 1]]
input after: [[1, 4], [2, 4]]
output [[1, 4]]
Input modified!
==> preserve_input = True
------> idx =  0
input before: [[-25, -14], [-21, -16], [-20, -15], [-10, -7], [-8, -5], [-6, -3], [2, 4], [2, 3], [3, 6], [12, 15], [13, 18], [14, 17], [22, 27], [25, 30], [26, 29]]
input after: [[-25, -14], [-21, -16], [-20, -15], [-10, -7], [-8, -5], [-6, -3], [2, 4], [2, 3], [3, 6], [12, 15], [13, 18], [14, 17], [22, 27], [25, 30], [26, 29]]
output [[-25, -14], [-10, -3], [2, 6], [12, 18], [22, 30]]
No change in input.
------> idx =  1
input before: [[4, 2], [3, 1]]
input after: [[4, 2], [3, 1]]
output [[1, 4]]
No change in input.
```