# How to merge overlapping date ranges stored as nested lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list which contains various nested lists, themselves always holding two [arrow objects](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) constituting date ranges from a start date (index 0) to an end date (index 1).

I aim to merge any overlapping lists, then sorting them chronologically.

```py
import arrow

date_range_lst = [
    [arrow.get("2020-01-05"), arrow.get("2020-02-26")],
    [arrow.get("2020-02-07"), arrow.get("2020-02-08")],
    [arrow.get("2020-05-16"), arrow.get("2020-07-28")],
    [arrow.get("2020-02-25"), arrow.get("2020-03-19")],
    [arrow.get("2020-05-15"), arrow.get("2020-05-16")],
    [arrow.get("2021-03-01"), arrow.get("2021-04-01")],
    [arrow.get("2021-05-05"), arrow.get("2021-08-08")],
]

date_range_merged_lst = []

# Code here

print(date_range_merged_lst)
```

For the above example, the intended output would look like this (done manually, but should be correct):

```
[[<Arrow [2020-01-05T00:00:00+00:00]>, <Arrow [2020-03-19T00:00:00+00:00]>],
[<Arrow [2020-05-15T00:00:00+00:00]>, <Arrow [2020-07-28T00:00:00+00:00]>],
[<Arrow [2021-03-01T00:00:00+00:00]>, <Arrow [2021-04-01T00:00:00+00:00]>],
[<Arrow [2021-05-05T00:00:00+00:00]>, <Arrow [2021-08-08T00:00:00+00:00]>]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution by using the [merge library](https://github.com/AlexandreDecan/portion) by [Guybrush](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4582949/guybrush). None of the other solutions for similar problems found on this site worked for me (e.g. in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49071081/merging-overlapping-intervals-in-python) or [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43600878/merging-overlapping-intervals)).

```py
import arrow

import portion

def merge(inputs):
    intervals = [portion.closed(a, b) for a, b in inputs]
    merge = portion.Interval(*intervals)
    merge = [[i.lower, i.upper] for i in merge]
    return merge


date_range_lst = [
    [arrow.get("2020-01-05"), arrow.get("2020-02-26")],
    [arrow.get("2020-02-07"), arrow.get("2020-02-08")],
    [arrow.get("2020-05-16"), arrow.get("2020-07-28")],
    [arrow.get("2020-02-25"), arrow.get("2020-03-19")],
    [arrow.get("2020-05-15"), arrow.get("2020-05-16")],
    [arrow.get("2021-03-01"), arrow.get("2021-04-01")],
    [arrow.get("2021-05-05"), arrow.get("2021-08-08")],
]

date_range_lst_merged_manual = [
    [arrow.get("2020-01-05"), arrow.get("2020-03-19")],
    [arrow.get("2020-05-15"), arrow.get("2020-07-28")],
    [arrow.get("2021-03-01"), arrow.get("2021-04-01")],
    [arrow.get("2021-05-05"), arrow.get("2021-08-08")],
]


date_range_lst_merged_auto = merge(date_range_lst)

if date_range_lst_merged_manual == date_range_lst_merged_auto:
    print("Test passed")
else:
    print("Test failed")
```

Output:

```
Test passed
```