# How to group arrays based on the difference of last element of first array to the first element of its consecutive array?

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to python and this is what I am trying to do, suppose I have an array

```
array([[1.03, 1.1 ],
       [1.12, 1.25],
       [2.02, 2.09],
       [2.15, 3.79],
       [4.73, 4.8 ],
       [4.89, 5.06],
       [5.28, 5.35],
       [5.67, 5.91],
       [6.5 , 6.57],
       [6.68, 9.1 ]])
```

What I am trying to do is by comparing last element of [1.03, 1.1 ] i.e. '1.1' and first element of [1.12, 1.25] i.e. '1.12' and if the difference is less than 0.5, then define new array taking first element of [1.03, 1.1 ] i.e. '1.03' and last element of [1.12, 1.25] i.e. '1.12', then this new array should be followed with other elements of defined array. So basically I am grouping arrays based on difference of last element and first element of consecutive arrays I have tried to summarize my question in best possible way.
How to do this in python, I am trying to do this using loops, but failing miserably.

Comment: And what is the expected output?

Comment: [Almost duplicate question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43600878/merging-overlapping-intervals)

All you need to do is to copy the accepted answer, then replace overlap checking to (overlap + margin of 0.5) checking

Comment: sorry but this is expected output,array([[1.03, 1.25],
       [2.02, 3.79],
       [4.73, 5.91],
       [6.5 , 9.1 ]])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should give you the desired result, basically merging the intervals:

```
def group_intervals(a):
    ans = []

    curr = None
    for x in a:
        # no previous interval under consideration
        if curr == None:
            curr = x
        else:
            # check if we can merge the intervals
            if x[0]-curr[1] < 0.5:
                curr[1] = x[1]
            else:
            # if we cannot merge, push the current element to ans
                ans.append(curr)
                curr = x
    # making sure, the last interval is pushed into final answer
    if curr is not None:
        ans.append(curr)

    return ans
```

Comment: Maybe I have not explained myself correctly, based on the difference in elements of consecutive arrays I decide weather to combine them or not, e.g. output for above array would be,array([[1.03, 1.25], [2.02, 3.79], [4.73, 5.91], [6.5 , 9.1 ]])

Comment: @coolname11 there was an incorrect indentation which was causing incorrect results, now its fixed

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[1.03, 1.1 ],
       [1.12, 1.25],
       [2.02, 2.09],
       [2.15, 3.79],
       [4.73, 4.8 ],
       [4.89, 5.06],
       [5.28, 5.35],
       [5.67, 5.91],
       [6.5 , 6.57],
       [6.68, 9.1 ]])

def process(list_):
    for index in range(len(list_)-1):
        if list_[index+1][0] - list_[index][1] < 0.5: #perform comparison
            element_new = [list_[index][0], list_[index+1][1]] #new list element
            list_[index] = element_new #replace two old elements by the new elements
            list_.remove(list_[index+1])
            process(list_) #recursion
            break
    return list_

list1 = arr.tolist() #it is a good practice to perform remove/append action on list rather than numpy array
list2 = process(list1)
arr2 = np.array(list2)
print(arr2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done without any loops:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[1.03, 1.1 ],
       [1.12, 1.25],
       [2.02, 2.09],
       [2.15, 3.79],
       [4.73, 4.8 ],
       [4.89, 5.06],
       [5.28, 5.35],
       [5.67, 5.91],
       [6.5 , 6.57],
       [6.68, 9.1 ]])

toMerge = (arr[1:,0]-arr[:-1,1])<0.5          # flag neighbours to merged
breaks  = np.insert(toMerge==False,0,False)   # lines not merged with previous
starts  = np.insert(np.argwhere(breaks),0,0)  # indexes of start lines
ends    = np.append(starts[1:],breaks.size)-1 # indexes of end lines for merges 
result  = arr[starts]                         # keep only start lines
result[:,1] = arr[ends,1]                     # assign merged end values
```

output:

```
print(result)

[[1.03 1.25]
 [2.02 3.79]
 [4.73 5.91]
 [6.5  9.1 ]]
```

*note: this fixes issues with my previous answer*

If you are not using numpy, a simple loop can be used to produce the result:

```
result,prevEnd = arr[:1],arr[0][1]
for line in arr[1:]:
    start,end = line
    if start-prevEnd<0.5: result[-1][1] = end
    else:                 result.append(line)
    prevEnd = end
```

*This would work well on Python lists of lists but it would be very inefficient on numpy arrays*