# How to detect if each list in a list is overlapping with the other lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Hello I want to create a function that will take input as a list of lists and check if each list in that list is overlapping or entangling with each other. for e.g.

```
a = [[0.65, 0.71], [0.55, 0.65], [0.6, 0.66]]
```

here each of the lists in a are overlapping with each other. Since they are overlapping I want to return only the max and min from a. So, therefore, the function should return `[[0.55, 0.71]]` where `0.55` is the min in `a` and `0.71` is the max in `a`

case-2:

Say if there is another list `b =  [[0.65, 0.71], [0.55, 0.65], [0.1, 0.2]]`. But now since only the first two combinations are overlapping i.e.  `[[0.65, 0.71], [0.55, 0.65], [0.6, 0.66]]` now the function should return `[[0.55, 0.71], [0.1, 0.2]]`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merging Overlapping Intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43600878/merging-overlapping-intervals)

Comment: This seems to be a kind of competitive programming problem. Just posting the problem here and looking for solutions is not fair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens that I have written such a function recently:

```py
def remove_intersections(a):
    for i, (s1, e1) in enumerate(a):
        for j, (s2, e2) in enumerate(a):
            if i == j:
                continue
            if s2 <= s1 <= e2:
                del a[i]
                if j < i:
                    del a[j]
                else:
                    del a[j - 1]
                a.append([s2, max(e1, e2)])
                remove_intersections(a)
                return
            if s2 <= e1 <= e2:
                del a[i]
                if j < i:
                    del a[j]
                else:
                    del a[j - 1]
                a.append([min(s1, s2), e2])
                remove_intersections(a)
                return
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you!